# Having problems getting a MD file from firebase storage and read the contents in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, fetch, firebase-storage

I'm stuck in this problem for the last 2 days, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a React web app and some .md files stored in Firebase storage, whose content I want to read and render in a component. (don't ask why, I just want to do it for the shake of doing it)

I tried the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `markdown/${post.slug}.md`)).then((url) =>
      fetch(url).then((res) => console.log(res))
    );
  }, []);
```

where *markdown/${post.slug}.md* is the file in the storage folder.
That gives me a:

> Access to fetch at '.....' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

error, which after googling I lead me to the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `markdown/${post.slug}.md`)).then((url) =>
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        crossorigin: true,
        mode: "no-cors",
      }).then((res) => console.log(res))
    );
  }, []);
```

where I may no have the response I get is:

> Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: falseredirected: falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: "opaque"url: ""[[Prototype]]: Response

and I'm stuck there.

One last note:
The results are the same even if I make an asynchronous function in the useEffect, and I can render the file fine if I do it locally.

Comment: `.then(res => res.text()).then((res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: My bad, forgot that. That also gives the same results

Comment: How could `.text()` return a `Reponse` object?

Comment: your code without the cors, gives the same error, with the second code the text is empty. (The file is not)